# Session not stored after redirect?

Tags: php, session, authentication, undefined

Trying to store a user's role with
    `$_SESSION['role'] == $row['role'];`
When username 'admin' logs in, it checks for user role Admin in SQL and, if Admin exists, redirects user to admin.php
However when redirected to admin.php the page says that
    `$_SESSION['role']`
is undefined on that page.

I thought I defined it with
    `$_SESSION['role'] == $row['role']`
on login_action.php and using start_session() in both login_action.php and admin.php

What is wrong?

**login_action.php**

```
<?php
      session_start();
include("connect.php"); 
$tbl_name="users"; 

$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
$password = sha1($password);

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user='$username' AND password='$password'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1){
      echo "<script>alert(' Wrong Username or Password Access Denied !!! Try Again');
      window.location='index.php';
      </script>";
     }else{
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      $_SESSION['role'] == $row['role'];

      if($row['role'] == 'Admin'){
       header('location: admin.php');
       exit;

      else{
       echo "<script>alert('Wrong username or password. Try again');
      window.location='index.php';
      </script>";
      }
     }
```

**admin.php**

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['role']) != 'Admin') {
        echo "You are not the admin";
    }
    ?>

    <html>
      <head>
        <title> Administrator Page </title>
     <head>

    <body><br>
     <h1 align="center">
      Welcome To Administrator Page <br>



      <a href='logout.php'>Click here to log out</a>
      </h1>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your login_action.php :

change $_SESSION['role'] **==** $row['role']; to $_SESSION['role'] **=** $row['role'];

in your admin.php file:

**isset($_SESSION['role']) != 'Admin'**

isset($var) : returns true if $var is set and is not null.

The solution would be:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && strtolower($_SESSION['role']) != 'admin') {
    echo "You are not the admin";
}
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title> Administrator Page </title>
 <head>

<body><br>
 <h1 align="center">
  Welcome To Administrator Page <br>



  <a href='logout.php'>Click here to log out</a>
  </h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Not only solving my problem but enhancing it with strtolower. Much appreciated!

Comment: sure mate, don't hesitate to ask questions, that's what SO is for :)

Comment: Noticed that when value in role is something else than 'admin' and contains special characters (like å, ä or ö) I can't log in. Instead I am redirected back to index.php . Do you have any idea why? Both database and table are encoded with UTF8_bin

Comment: utf8_bin compares strings by the binary value of each character in the string, if characters are different (be it just case or diacritics difference) then your query might yield different results.

use utf8_unicode_ci instead.

Comment: Changed user table and database to utf8_unicode_ci but didn't work.  Perhaps something to do with a missing meta tag?

Comment: meta tag will only specify what character set is your website written with.
if you try to login and the role value is different that 'admin' then normally you shouldn't be able to access the admin dashboard.

Comment: if($row['role'] == 'Admin'){
       header('location: admin.php');
       exit;
      }else if($row['role'] == 'Head' ){
       header("Location: boss.php");
       exit;
      }else if($row['role'] == 'Bäot' ){
       header("Location: staff.php");
       exit;
      }

      else{
       echo "<script>alert('Wrong username or password. Try again');
      window.location='index.php';
      </script>";
      }
     }

Comment: I have different redirections depending on user roles, the only one not working is if user role is 'Bäot'

Comment: seems like the statement $row['role'] == 'Bäot' which involves unicode string comparison is the reason, try this [collator_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/collator.compare.php)

Comment: Found the solution! Instead of strtolower I had to use mb_strtolower , otherwise it would turn 'ä' in 'Bäot' to a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here:

**login_action.php**

```
else{
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role']; // <--- Notice only one equal

      if($row['role'] == 'Admin'){ // = inside if statement is always true
       header('location: admin.php');
       exit;
```

Comment: Thanks Savandy! So simple, but still helping me out a lot. Learning by my own mistakes.